# Autoware 1.14.0 build error: ‘Index’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow [autoware wiki](https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki/Source-Build#how-to-build)  to build autoware 1.14.0 step by step, when I begin to build (without CUDA), error occurs:

```
error: ‘Index’ in namespace ‘Eigen’ does not name a type   return state_(static_cast<Eigen::Index>(IDX::X));
```

my environment: ubuntu 18.04 ros Melodic ,Eigen 3.2.10

and here is my [error log](https://gist.github.com/LongruiDong/2a18d4ed5c2eee49d446da5bbdf484af) from terminal

So how can I solve this error?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384820/autoware-1.14.0-build-error:-%E2%80%98index%E2%80%99-in-namespace-%E2%80%98eigen%E2%80%99-does-not-name-a-type/) by [LongruiDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/50002/longruidong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2021-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok,  It is because the version of Eigen is old, I downgrade autoware to 1.12.0 and update Eigen to 3.3.7, and then build successfully.

---

Originally posted by [LongruiDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/50002/longruidong/) with karma: 26 on 2021-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1